# Specifying Other Amount on Initial Web Page

Tags: button, payment

I have a form that contains a drop-down selector for someone to choose from one of three items  to make a payment.  I am trying to add a fourth item so that someone can specify their amount on the initial web page before clicking the "pay with paypal" button I created.

The ID of my text input box for the "other amount" is:  amount1

Is it possible to use the advanced variables section of the Paypal button generator to have the value for the amount be set to the value from this text input box.

option_amount3   is the variable name that refers to the fourth option in the drop-down selector, so can I do something like:    option_amount3 = [some way to grab the value typed into the text input box]

Here's a link to the page:

http://freeonlinetherapy.net/index_dave.html

Please advise.....

Comment: Please advise what you've tried so far

Comment: The only thing I got to work was to set this option variable to a fixed amount through the Paypal button generator.  The part I am missing is the code I would use to set the value of this option variable from user input on the initial web page form.